# jQuery get the class of the current element from a jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery

```
$('.colorpicker').colpick({
layout:'hex',
        submit:0,
        colorScheme:'dark',
        onChange:function(hsb, hex, rgb, fromSetColor) {
            if (!fromSetColor) $('.colorpicker').val(hex).css('background-color', '#' + hex);
        }
});
```

How can I target only this element instead of all the `$(".colorpicker")` inside the `onChange` function? I tried `$(this)` and it doesn't work.

**UPDATE**

I've included the contents

```
<label for='field-32'>Colour 2</label>
                        <input data-question-id='32' type='text' name='question-32'   id='field-32' class='colorpicker question-field field form-control' value="" />

<script>
$(window).load(function() {

    $('.colorpicker').colpick({
    layout:'hex',
            submit:0,
            colorScheme:'dark',
            onChange:function(hsb, hex, rgb, fromSetColor) {
                if (!fromSetColor) $(fromSetColor).val(hex).css('background-color', '#' + hex);
                console.log(this);
            }
    }).keyup(function(){
        $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);
            });
    });

</script>
```

**UPDATE 2**

JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/9p6ac/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(window).load(function() {

$('.colorpicker').colpick({
       layout:'hex',            
        colorScheme:'dark',
        onSubmit:function(hsb, hex, rgb, fromSetColor) {
            if (!fromSetColor) $(fromSetColor).val(hex).css('background-color', '#' + hex);

        }
   }).keyup(function(){
        $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);
    });
});
```

Assumed `.colorpicker` selector applied in input textbox.

Ref: http://colpick.com/plugin

Section: Example - Color boxes using onSubmit callback and rgbhex layout

Comment: Sorry no its not changing anything. When I console.log(fromSetColor) its undefined

Comment: Are you using input element or div element?

Comment: Ca you post your html part here ?

Comment: input and i've applied teh colorpicker class to it. sure

Comment: Can you add some static id for input elements like id="picker1" ... Or can you provide the fiddle demo?

Comment: I have like 3 or more colorpickers on a page, and its dynamic, and the user can add more colorpickers. So tried to keep it simple with classes. I've updated the question with contents. I'll add the jsfiddle.